# Ways to represent float infinity in C++

Tags: c++, stl, conventions, infinity

I want to express floating-point infinity in C++ for my program.
I came across two ways to achieve this: using `INFINITY` and `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`.

Both options seem to work, but I'm unsure which one is the better choice.
On one hand, `INFINITY` is a simple macro defined in math.h, making it easy to use.
On the other hand, `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` is a function from `<limits>` and is part of the C++ STL, which seems to be a conventional way.

#### In summary:

Should I use `INFINITY` or `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` to represent floating-point infinity in my C++ program?
Which one is considered a better practice, and are there any performance or portability considerations I should be aware of?

Comment: Simple rule: don’t use (legacy) macros when you can use a strongly-typed function instead.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information! Could you post it as an answer so that I can accept?

Comment: Do you have a particular reason to use `float` instead of `double`?

Comment: Nothing much. The library that I'm using right now works with both.
I just want to put infinity as an argument, so precision won't be a problem for me.  
P.S. I realized the function uses double as an argument. Will change the type from `float` to `double`, thank you!

Comment: @KonradRudolph -- the type of [`INFINITY`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/INFINITY) is `float`, just like the return type of `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Macros were introduced in C to express things that couldn’t be expressed well otherwise in the language. In this particular example, `INFINITY` names a compile-time constant.

C++ introduces different ways *into the language* that allow you to express the same things that you used to need macros for in C (in many, but not all circumstances). Regarding this particular case, C++ has a way of naming compile-time constants in various ways.

Compared to `INFINITY`, using `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()` has the following advantages:

- It is properly scoped inside a namespace, which means that other code can use the identifier `infinity` to denote other things without causing name clashes.
- It is strongly typed and *names* a type, so that `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` can be specialised for different values of `T`, and it can be used without conversion in generic contexts.
- It is part of the language (rather than a separate preprocessor language), which makes it easier for third-party tooling (e.g. IDEs) to interact with it.

For historical reasons, `infinity()` is a *function* but this isn’t terribly important because (since it’s `constexpr`) you can use it in any context in which you could use any other constant expression.

Conversely, compared to `std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity()`, using `INFINITY` has the following advantages:

- It is shorter.

Comment: We could add an argument: if using modules and C++23 `import std;`, the macro `INFINITY` won't work because macros are never exported in modules. But `std::numeric_limits<T>::infinity()` will work.

Comment: The type of `INFINITY` is `float`. Can't get more strongly typed than that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Okay, maybe I should have said “correctly typed”. ;-)